# Django model not updating with manage.py

Tags: django-models

I'm using Django with Google Appengine.  I've amended my models in my development environment and when I run `manage.py makemigrations` and `manage.py migrate` I'm informed no changes have been made but when I run my app I get a 1054 unknown column error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I've solved it in the development environment - I'm not sure what I'll do in production once it is live.

1. I cleared the databases completely using MySQL

   `drop database mydb;`

   `create database mydb;`
2. I deleted the migrations folder from my directory structure
3. `manage.py makemigrations myapp`
4. `manage.py migrate myapp`

Answer (score 1):

`manage.py migrate` does **not** check that all the tables are correct, and match the model. It just checks the migrations log.

If the migration log says that everything was migrated, then django will not change the database - even if some tables are wrong.

Since It's your development environment, you can simply drop the database, create it again, and run `manage.py migrate`.

Comment: How do I then migrate to the live database?

Comment: That's an issue. You will need to find what went wrong and fix it manually with ALTER TABLE, to bring the DB to a known state. There are tools that will find schema diffs between two databases, so check where production is different from a clean fully migrated DB